# Rails: PostgreSQL Array not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to work with Arrays and my db is PostgreSQL. I did the below migration.

```
add_column :articles, :tags, :text, array: true, default: []
add_index  :articles, :tags, using: 'gin'
```

And these information may help to check:

```
> rails db
psql (9.3.12)
Type "help" for help.
```

and in rails console:

```
irb(main):087:0* article.tags.class
=> ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
```

and when I check it through the psql:

```
     Column     |            Type             |                          
----------------+-----------------------------+------------------------
 tags     | text[]                      | default '{}'::text[]
```

So, it seems that everything is Ok but I have a problem to save the data. I have tried different ways in the rails console such as:

```
Article.create(author: "test", tags: ["2", "3"])
```

and

```
irb(main):074:0> article.tags = ['3']
=> ["3"]
irb(main):081:0> article.tags_will_change!
=> {}
```

but the result is nothing and tags is still empty! (`tags: {}`)

Also, I cannot use `+=`, `<<` and `push` method in the console because of the errors like:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `push' for {}:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
```

Anyone can help? What is the solution?

Comment: Any chance you have a method named "tags" in Article class?

Comment: have you use the hstore gem?

Comment: I would suggest trying to temporarily comment out some gems from gemfile. I once had a case where one of popular gems would define 'tags' method for my ActiveRecord models, overwriting the old one.